# Qt Creator not showing border image of Qlabel after migration from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qlabel

So I am making an GUI in Qt, my problem is that Qt seems to ignore border image of Qlabel. Here is my `cards.qrc`:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>----.bmp</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Here is the code:

```
ClickableLabel::ClickableLabel(const QString& text) : QLabel()
{
    this->setStyleSheet("QLabel { border-image : url(----.bmp); color : red; }");
}
```

And I added this line in .pro file:

```
RESOURCES += cards.qrc
```

Everything worked perfectly fine when I had this code in visual studio, no in Qt Creator it seems to ignore this image. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed ':' symbol in the path to the resource file.
Change your stylesheet like this:

```
this->setStyleSheet("QLabel { border-image : url(:/----.bmp); color : red; }");
```